# MSP430 i2c txn buffer not moving second buffer command

Tags: i2c, embedded, delay, msp430, texas-instruments

In this code i have used B0 I2C module.
Problem - I f i I2C_Txn_byte() to send any command it sends the it the first time but doesn't get in the interrupt ISR again
for Example

```
I2C_Txn_byte(0x01,0x02,0x03)           //this will be executed 
I2C_Txn_byte(0x01,0x02,0x04)           //this will not be executed
```

although in second command it enters the I2C_Txn_byte() function but never sends the data to buffer because of not entering the buffer
Small tweak- I have included a delay in I2C_Txn_byte function which solves my problem but doesn't seems like a neat solution

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <I2C_header.h>
#include <Peripherals.h>

uint8_t slave_dara_reg=0;
uint8_t TxnBuff[50];
uint8_t Txbyte=0;
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0;
uint8_t stop=0;
uint8_t byte=0;
int i;




void I2C_GPIO();
void I2C_ini();
void I2C_Txn(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t *value);
void I2C_Txn_byte(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t value);



void I2C_GPIO()
{
    P2SEL|=BIT0;                   // Set P2.0,P2.1 to UCB0SCL, UCB0SDA
    P2SEL|=BIT1;
}


void I2C_ini()
{
    UCB0CTLW0|=UCSWRST;                                 // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTLW0|=UCMST | UCMODE_3 | UCSSEL_1;             // I2C Master, use ACLK
    UCB0BRW_L=160;                                        // fSCL = ACLK/1 = ~32768Hz
    UCB0BRW_H=0;
    UCB0CTLW0&=~UCSWRST;                                // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE0;                                    // Enable TX interrupt
}

void I2C_Txn_byte(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t value)
{
    for(i=5000;i>0;i--);                                //delay
    slave_dara_reg=slave_Dadd;                          //Slave data register
    TxnBuff[0]=value;                                   //Transmit data buffer
    Txbyte=1;

    UCB0I2CSA=slave_add;                              //Slave selected base address
    UCB0IFG&=~(UCTXIFG+UCRXIFG);                        // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE&=~UCRXIE;                                    // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE;                                     // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTL1|=UCTR+UCTXSTT;                         // I2C TX, start condition
}


void I2C_Txn(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t *value)
{
    slave_dara_reg=slave_Dadd;                          //Slave data register
    CopyBuffer(TxnBuff,value);                          //Transmit data buffer

    UCB0I2CSA=slave_add;                              //Slave selected base address
    UCB0IFG&=~(UCTXIFG+UCRXIFG);                        // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE&=~UCRXIE;                                    // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE;                                     // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTL1|=UCTR+UCTXSTT;                         // I2C TX, start condition
}

void CopyBuffer(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest)
{
    volatile uint8_t i=0;
    while(dest[i]!='\0')
    {
        source[i]=dest[i];
        i++;
        Txbyte++;
    }
}





#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_B0_VECTOR))) USCI_B0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  //Must read from UCB0RXBUF
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB0IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
  {
    case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
      break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:  break;         // Vector 22: RXIFG0
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
              UCB0TXBUF=slave_dara_reg;
              if(Txbyte)
              {
                  UCB0TXBUF=TxnBuff[TransmitIndex++];
                  Txbyte--;
                  byte++;

                  if(Txbyte!=0)
                  {
                      for(i=5000;i>0;i--);      //delay
                  }
                  if(Txbyte==0)
                  {
                      LED4_OUT^=LED4_BIT;
                      //Done with transmission
                      UCB0CTLW0|=UCTXSTP;                     //Send stop condition
                      UCB0IE&=~UCTXIE;                        //disable TX interrupt
                      stop++;
                  }
              }
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't respond before so I'm not going to write, now. Best wishes.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: my bad ,I am new to this platform, please help me with this problem

Comment: Which MSP430 processor are you using? Did you start with the TI sample code for i2C? The sample code sometimes has imperfections, but it is a good starting point. The one I use has a state machine because the multiple interupts need to be handled differently. I did need to add code to the start of each I2C command so it will wait until the previous transaction is complete before continuing (check for IDLE_MODE).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am using MSP430F6736 ,and  secondly I matched this code with Ti sample code . The problem is when i use uscb0stat usb0busy command it doesn't make it right but when i use delay it works fine any tips how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TI sample code uses low-power mode (sleep) to block the main code until the I2C transaction is complete. Without these (or kludgy delays), the code will try to start the next transaction too soon. I added them to your code, search for *****. Note that my MSP430 is different so you may need to tweek these instructions.

Coincidentally, I am working on a project that uses I2C. I added some scope plots so you can see what is happening. I am toggling a discrete in my code. The "start" command writes the first byte (slave address). The HW has double buffers so it is immediately ready for the second byte. It is in sleep mode between "start" and "done", momentarily woken up to service the interrupts.

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <I2C_header.h>
#include <Peripherals.h>

uint8_t slave_dara_reg=0;
uint8_t TxnBuff[50];
uint8_t Txbyte=0;
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0;
uint8_t stop=0;
uint8_t byte=0;
int i;




void I2C_GPIO();
void I2C_ini();
void I2C_Txn(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t *value);
void I2C_Txn_byte(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t value);



void I2C_GPIO()
{
    P2SEL|=BIT0;                   // Set P2.0,P2.1 to UCB0SCL, UCB0SDA
    P2SEL|=BIT1;
}


void I2C_ini()
{
    UCB0CTLW0|=UCSWRST;                                 // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTLW0|=UCMST | UCMODE_3 | UCSSEL_1;             // I2C Master, use ACLK
    UCB0BRW_L=160;                                        // fSCL = ACLK/1 = ~32768Hz
    UCB0BRW_H=0;
    UCB0CTLW0&=~UCSWRST;                                // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE0;                                    // Enable TX interrupt
}

void I2C_Txn_byte(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t value)
{
    for(i=5000;i>0;i--);                                //delay
    slave_dara_reg=slave_Dadd;                          //Slave data register
    TxnBuff[0]=value;                                   //Transmit data buffer
    Txbyte=1;

    UCB0I2CSA=slave_add;                              //Slave selected base address
    UCB0IFG&=~(UCTXIFG+UCRXIFG);                        // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE&=~UCRXIE;                                    // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE;                                     // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTL1|=UCTR+UCTXSTT;                         // I2C TX, start condition
}


void I2C_Txn(uint8_t slave_add,uint8_t slave_Dadd,uint8_t *value)
{
    slave_dara_reg=slave_Dadd;                          //Slave data register
    CopyBuffer(TxnBuff,value);                          //Transmit data buffer

    UCB0I2CSA=slave_add;                              //Slave selected base address
    UCB0IFG&=~(UCTXIFG+UCRXIFG);                        // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE&=~UCRXIE;                                    // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE|=UCTXIE;                                     // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTL1|=UCTR+UCTXSTT;                         // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts *****
}

void CopyBuffer(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest)
{
    volatile uint8_t i=0;
    while(dest[i]!='\0')
    {
        source[i]=dest[i];
        i++;
        Txbyte++;
    }
}





#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_B0_VECTOR))) USCI_B0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  //Must read from UCB0RXBUF
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB0IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
  {
    case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
      break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:  break;         // Vector 22: RXIFG0
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
              UCB0TXBUF=slave_dara_reg;
              if(Txbyte)
              {
                  UCB0TXBUF=TxnBuff[TransmitIndex++];
                  Txbyte--;
                  byte++;

                  if(Txbyte!=0)
                  {
                      for(i=5000;i>0;i--);      //delay
                  }
                  if(Txbyte==0)
                  {
                      LED4_OUT^=LED4_BIT;
                      //Done with transmission
                      UCB0CTLW0|=UCTXSTP;                     //Send stop condition
                      UCB0IE&=~UCTXIE;                        //disable TX interrupt
                      stop++;
                      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0 *****
                  }
              }
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir your reply help me to understand what was the issue , I am somewhat a intermediate and trying to code msp430f6736 can you sir please help me with some small issues , I am trying to solve them since a week working 10+hrs daily on them , I will be obelized if somehow I can connect with you and rectify the issues